# Не понимаю как работать с Google Maps в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api, google-maps, react-hook

**Нужно подключить Google Maps в проект, написанный на React (с возможностью автозаполнения, построения маршрута, выбора способа передвижения).
Подключила API в index.html в head через тег script в формате:**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places
```

**В компоненте создаю экземпляр карты и подключаю autocomplete и directions в useEffect:**

```
  let map, marker, directionsRenderer, directionsService, autocomplete, place;
  const classes = useStyles()
  const ref = useRef(null)
  const inputRef = useRef(null)
  const controlRef = useRef(null)
  const [routeType, setRouteType] = useState(routeTypes.driving);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState(null)
  const position = {
    lat: Number(apartment.geolocation.split(',')[0]),
    lng: Number(apartment.geolocation.split(',')[1])
    };

  useEffect(() => {
      map = new google.maps.Map(ref.current, {
        center: position,
        zoom: 13,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        clickableIcons: false,
      });
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: '/images/map/marker.svg'
      });
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputRef.current, {
        componentRestrictions: { country: "ru" },
      });

      directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()
      directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()
      directionsRenderer.setMap(map)

      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        marker.setVisible(false);
        setAddress(place);
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(place)
      });
  }, [])
```

**Мне нужно вызывать функцию calculateAndDisplayRoute каждый раз при изменении routeType.**

```
   const calculateAndDisplayRoute = (addressTo) => {
    directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(position),
        destination: addressTo.geometry.location,
        travelMode: routeType,
      },
      (response, status) => {
        if (status === "OK") {
          directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

**Поэтому я вызываю ее в useEffect:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (address) {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(address)
    }
  }, [routeType])
```

**Но переменная directionsService имеет значение undefined, хотя я перезаписываю ее в useEffect.**
Мне нужно изменять маршрут на карте при выборе другого способа передвижения, но я не могу достучаться до нужной переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Вынесла объявление за компонент, все заработало